# object Object displayed after inserting row into HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a dialog box that will open up on the press of a button. I can then fill out the form and press submit, and it inserts the row correctly in to the table.

However, after submitting the form, the newly inserted row displays as the following immediately after being submitted:
[image]

So it works, but just displays the [object Object] after each value. Once I refresh the page it goes away as you can see here:
[image]

How can I fix my code so that it removes the [object Object] completely after inserting a row?

HTML form:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="buyer_id">Buyer ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="buyer_id" id="buyer_id" value="">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
      <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
      <label for="buyer">Buyer Department</label>
      <input type="text" name="buyer" id="buyer" value="">
      <input type="submit" id="submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Javascript function:

```
function addVendor() {

      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      console.log(allFields);
      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#replenishment_table tbody tr" ).eq(0).clone();
        var dict = {};
        var errors = "";
        $.each(allFields, function(){
          $tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val()+"-"+name );
          var type = $(this).attr('id');
          var value = $(this).val();
//        console.log(type + " : " + value);
          // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
          switch (type) {
            case "buyer_id":
                dict["Buyer-id"] = value;
              break;
            case "name":
                dict["Name"] = value;
              break;
            case "phone":
                dict["Phone"] = value;
              break;
            case "email":
                dict["Email"] = value;
              break;
            case "buyer":
                dict["Buyer_Department"] = value;
              break;
            }
        });

        if (valid) {

        $( "#replenishment_table tbody" ).append($tr);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
        console.log(dict);

       var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "insert.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row inserted");
            //queryTable();
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to insert");
            console.log(response);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });

      } else {
        alert(errors);
      }

      }
      return valid;
    }
```

insert.php code:

```
// connection details
// ..
// ..
// ..
  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$host;Database=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPass);
  $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

  $sql = "INSERT INTO TableXYZ ([Buyer-id], Name, Phone, Email, [Buyer_Department]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

  $result = $stmt->execute(array($buyer_id, $name, $phone, $email, $buyer));

  echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[object Object]` is generated when you "to string" a javascript object, a simple example:

```
var x = {}; 
var s = x.toString(); 
if (s === "[object Object]") console.log("object")
```

This is frequently seen when people try `alert(myvar)` but can also occur when concatenating an object as a string.

In this case, the line:

```
$tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val()+"-"+name);
```

is appending `"-" + name` which, if `name` is an object will generate the nefarious `-[object Object]`